# Calculate new height from width and aspect ratio

Tags: formula, aspect-ratio

I have an image that is 1368*1026

I have calculated the aspect ratio by doing 1368 / 1026 = 0.8746355685131195

I want the image to be 500 pixels wide, how do I use the aspect ratio to calculate the height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w=1368` and `h=1026`, so `r=w/h`. Let's say `w2` and `h2` is what you're looking for, with `w2=500`. We also have `w2/h2=r`, so, `500/h2=r`. We can re-arrange and have `h2=500/r`. With that I get `h2=375`.

PS: `1368/1026` is `1,33...` not `0.87...`.